# ngReact: watch-depth attribute types explained

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, ngreact

Recently I found an awesome library that allows for React components to be used in Angular applications, called **[ngReact](https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact)**

My question is about the **watch-depth** attribute that can be declared on a reactDirective component:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="helloController">
    <hello-component watch-depth="reference" fname="person.fname" lname="person.lname"></hello-component>
  </div>
</body>
```

Looking at ngReact documentation for the **[reactDirective service](https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact#the-reactdirective-service)** I see that there are 3 possible values for watch-depth:

- **Reference**
- **Collection**
- **Value**

In my initial exploration using ngReact I have been sticking with using the default **value** option.

*My question is, what are the differences between these types?*

Simple examples for when each watch-depth type is ideal to use would be great!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer has to do with how angular's $watch works.  There are 3 ways angular applies $watch: Reference, Collection, Value (as you've already mentioned).

Reference:

Reference looks at the reference of a value and will only register a change (and cause a rerender) if that reference changes.  This is the least expensive watch type.
example of a reference change:

```
$scope.userArray = newUserArray
```

Collection:

A watch-depth of Collection is more in depth.  It will look inside the collection.  It will register a change if a Watch By Reference would have fired, or if a new item is added, removed, or reordered within the collection.

```
$scope.userArray.push(newUser);
```

Value:

A watch-depth of value is the most expensive. It will watch the values within a collection.  It will register a change if Watch By Reference would have fired, if Watch By Collection would have fired, or if a value within the collection changes.

```
$scope.userArray[0].age = 32;
```

This answer was heavily inspired by an excellent article written by Tero Parviainen,
https://teropa.info/blog/2014/01/26/the-three-watch-depths-of-angularjs.html